# Wifi connection with router breaks too often at certain hours in 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

Good time of day.
I have a problem. My laptop keeps disconnecting from wifi in several minutes at certain hours daily: 20:00 - 21:20. I am the only user connected to this router. It's a bit annoying. Perhaps, it can happen due to wireless routers from my neighbors, that may interfere.

```
satana@satana:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Gnome 3.28.1
Kernel 4.15.0-20-generic

Router model Trendnet TEW 432 BRP. Wireless G broadband router
Firmware model 3.10.20

Here is the data about the model of laptop.

satana@satana:~$ sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
Lenovo B50-10

satana@satana:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 1c:39:47:36:07:05
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:92 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90504000-90504fff memory:90500000-90503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c0:90:4c:f7:d0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.10.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Thank You for Your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of wifi power management setups.

We fixed that issue by changing power management options in Ubuntu.

```
$ nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Change **wifi.powersave from 3 to 2**.